# Sum of std::vector<Object> members C++

Tags: c++, sum, stdvector, accumulate

I have Example Class:

```
class Example {
private:
  int testValue1;
  int testValue2;
  int testValue3;

public:
  Example(int pVal1, int pVal2, int pVal3);

  Example(const Example);

  const Example operator =(const Example);

  inline int getValue1() { return testValue1; }

  inline int getValue2() { return testValue2; }

  inline int getValue3() { return testValue3; }

};
```

In source code I have std::vector of Example Objects.

Is it possible with some std::algorithm, std::numeric functions make a sum of Value1 of all Obejcts in vector

something like this:
std::accumulate(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0, SomeFunctorOrOthers)....

Of course I can use an iterators... but if it is possible ii want to know it

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14):

Sure:

```
int sum = 
std::accumulate (begin(v), end(v), 0, 
    [](int i, const Object& o){ return o.getValue1() + i; });
```

Note that, since `Object` is passed by const-ref to the lambda, you need to make getters `const` (that's a good practice anyway).

If you don't have C++11, you can define a functor with overloaded `operator()`. I'd go further and make it a template so you can easily decide which of the getters you'd like to call:

```
template<int (Object::* P)() const> // member function pointer parameter
struct adder {
    int operator()(int i, const Object& o) const
    {
        return (o.*P)() + i;
    }  
};
```

Pass it like this to algorithm: `adder<&Object::getValue2>()`

Comment: what trick int i is doing here?

Comment: It's the first parameter to the lambda function. The 'accumulate' algorithm uses it to pass the running sum.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::accumulate(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0, [](const int& a, Example& b)
{
return a + b.getValue1();
});
```

Comment: How to make it work where the member data type is float.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

It's enough if you overload operator casting for `int`:

```
class Example {
  ...

  operator int()  { return testValue1; }
};
```

The drawback is, you may don't want this overload generally applies in your class.

Comment: I would not consider this a good reason to provide something as generic (and dangerous) as an implicit conversion to `int`.

Comment: I myself don't like this, but it's just another approach. Since class `Example` is just an example, this solution maybe not really bad.